# Tableau- Pie Chart with Multiple Measure Values

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a pie chart to profile the percent each of the measures below (see attached link to image of my data) represent out of the total for all measures. Since the data are all separate measures/variables, Tableau will not let me automatically create a pie chart for them. Does anyone know what I would need to do to allow me to visually display the data in the method I've described above?

[image: Image of Current Data]

Answer (score 1):

Please see the below link:

http://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/creating-a-pie-chart-using-multiple-measures

Basically:

1. On a new view, on the marks card in the drop down select "Pie"
2. Drag the pill "Measure Values" into the "Size" card
3. Drag the pill "Measure Names" into the "Color" card
4. Right click the "Measure Name" pill in the marks card and select "Filter" to get rid of any measures you don't want included.